# Graphical models and conditional independence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, bayesian

[image: directed model]

Assume we have such a simple graphical directed model of probability. As a consequence we can factorize joint probability as following: $$p(x,y,z)=p(y|x,z)p(x|z)p(z)=p(y|x,z)p(x)p(z)$$

In directed graphical model every random variable can be written in the conditional (in)dependence context. My question is following: whether $p(x|z)=p(x)$ is a consequence of conditional independence rule or independence rule? Independence of variables implies conditional independence?

1) In case of conditional independence,  can we  say that: $$x \perp z,y |0 $$ so as a result $$p(x|0,z,y)=p(x|0)=p(x)$$ ?? Can we  even condition on zero?

2) In case of not conditional independence,things are much more clear: $$p(x|z)=\frac{p(x)p(z)}{p(z)}=p(x)$$

3)Here is some kind of appendix for question 1) (conditional independence of given graphical directed model):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion $p(x|z) = p(x)$ is just a consequence of the independence of $X$ and $Z$, and the reason is just what you show in part 2)

For part 1), we can introduce $0$ anyway, but we cannot get $x\perp z,y|0$ because there is an edge from $x$ to $y$. By this graph we **cannot** even get $x\perp z|y$ because in the moral graph there is an edge between $x$ and $z$.